# "asyncDataDefaults" is not exported by "virtual:nuxt

Tags: node.js, vue.js, deployment, nuxt.js, netlify

to run my vue project on netlify and during the pnpm run build command I take the following error :   ERROR  "asyncDataDefaults" is not exported by "virtual:nuxt:C:/Users/VasilisKaramanis/Desktop/cv_vue_copy/.nuxt/nuxt.config.mjs", imported by "node_modules/nuxt/dist/app/composables/asyncData.js"

Personally,  I don't know how to handle it and where is the problem !! If somebody has any solution or any command that would help I would be very pleasant [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emevB.png)

Answer (score 0):

I saw the same error message using vue 3.3.8 with nuxt ^3.8.0. Reverting to nuxt 3.7.4 resolved the issue. Deleting my app's node_modules folder and re-running `npm up` also resolved the issue.